# Subset data frame based on column values containing factors of a value

Tags: r, dataframe, time, subset

I have a data frame that contains a column with time differences (in hours) between the previous row and the current row. The rows are as such one long sequence.

I want to subset the data frame so the time differences are regular (16h), and delete rows that are not part of a 16-hour 'step'. However, an NA time difference should not just be skipped in calculations (e.g. rows with time differences 8, 8 together are a step of 16h, but three rows with 8, NA, 8, are not). Instead, calculating the 16h time differences should initiate again starting from this NA.

So where one or multiple time differences are 4 or 8 hours but together cannot be reduced to a single step of 16h, the individual values should be turned NA too, see below.

When a step of 16 hours is formed between, say row 1-3 or row 1-4, then row 2 or row 2-3 should be deleted respectively.

Unfortunately the answer provided previously does not seem to work with my data, only a fraction of '16h steps' are retained in the output. I have provided a new example below, as my example was likely not representative, as well as the code given to me

Input:

```
test

ID      Datetime        diff_h
134_18  7/27/2018 0:00  NA
134_18  7/27/2018 19:00 19
134_18  7/28/2018 0:00  5
134_18  7/28/2018 8:00  8
134_18  7/28/2018 16:00 8
134_18  7/29/2018 0:00  8
134_18  7/29/2018 8:00  8
134_18  7/29/2018 12:00 4
134_18  7/30/2018 16:00 4
134_18  7/30/2018 20:00 4
134_18  7/30/2018 16:00 8
134_18  7/31/2018 0:00  8
134_18  7/31/2018 8:00  8
134_18  7/31/2018 16:00 8
134_18  8/1/2018 8:00   16
134_18  8/1/2018 16:00  8
134_18  8/2/2018 0:00   8
134_18  8/2/2018 8:00   8
134_18  8/2/2018 16:00  8
```

(Just a sample, there's thousands more rows)
Note that in the code, I suggested the deleted  `%>% select(-grp) %>%` as it returned an 'unused argument' error!

```
data1 <- test %>% 
  group_by(ID, grp = rleid(diff_h %/% 16)) %>% 
  mutate(diff_h = cumsum(diff_h), 
         diff_h = replace(diff_h, n() ==1 & diff_h != 16, NA_real_))  %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  filter(diff_h == 16|is.na(diff_h))

data1
134_18  7/27/2018 0:00  NA  1
134_18  7/27/2018 19:00 NA  2
134_18  8/1/2018 8:00   16  4
134_18  8/2/2018 0:00   16  5
```

While the output I need is

```
ID  Datetime    diff_h
134_18  7/27/2018 0:00  NA
134_18  7/27/2018 19:00 NA
134_18  7/28/2018 0:00  NA
134_18  7/28/2018 16:00 16
134_18  7/29/2018 8:00  16
134_18  7/29/2018 12:00 NA
134_18  7/30/2018 16:00 16
134_18  7/31/2018 8:00  16
134_18  7/31/2018 16:00 NA
134_18  8/1/2018 8:00   16
134_18  8/2/2018 0:00   16
134_18  8/2/2018 16:00  16
```

Comment: This is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73086694/upsample-temporal-resolution-based-on-time-difference-values-in-r-data-frame#73086694

Comment: I accidentally created a new question, but deleted it , sorry. I have updated my original post to reflect the trouble I am having.

Answer (score 5):

We could create a grouping column with `rleid` and then get the cumulative sum by grp and 'ID', and `filter` only the '16' values or the `NA` elements

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID, grp = rleid(timediff %/% 16)) %>% 
  mutate(timediff = cumsum(timediff), 
  timediff = replace(timediff, n() ==1 & timediff != 16, NA_real_))  %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-grp) %>%
  filter(timediff == 16|is.na(timediff))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  ID     dist timediff
  <chr> <int>    <dbl>
1 A        12       NA
2 A         6       16
3 A         2       16
4 A         6       NA
5 B         7       NA
6 B         2       16
```